# Path to Layout.xml in magento

Tags: magento

Please I need the location of the layout XML file from a magento instance.

Comment: You may want to look for local.xml instead. It will be in your theme's layout folder if it exists (app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml -- replace "base" with your package and "default" with your theme name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Go to this path

***app/design/frontend/'your package'/'your theme'/layout/local.xml [ all xml files located here ]***

Hope solve your problem......